# Add a delay to cursor-listener in a-frame

Tags: href, aframe, webvr

i would like to have an a-entity with a cursor listener that triggers a  window.location.href but only gazing the object for more than 2 seconds? It's possible ... something like this

http://gasolin.idv.tw/aframe-href-component/basic/link.html

but without an external component in a-frame

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cursor` has a property called `fuseTimeout`:

```
cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
```

Just set it to any miliseconds value.
You can find it in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/cursor.html#example).